# Gray color, green background problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here's the pretty basic issue

[image]

"votes" is almost invisible on such background, though only answer boxes are affected.

[stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) will get you more of these, but
[the issue is not reproducible on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer)

Comment: Just removing that text completely would solve it well enough.

Comment: Or maybe make "votes" white when it is on the green background.

Comment: @iCodez, yeah, [that'd be ideal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) :)

Comment: Which "votes" do you mean?

Comment: The word votes appears under the number 17 in the above screenshots, it is just nearly invisible as indicated by the OP.

Comment: @CatherineMacInnes: I'm sorry, I forgot to include the sarcasm tags in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fixed for this. The change will go live after our next production build.